# I get an unexpected error in Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, exception, serversocket

I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
  at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
  at test.SocketTest.main(SocketTest.java:26)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I don't know why I get it. Any idea?

I'm using this code:

for Client:

```
public class SocketTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 5000);
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        Request request = new Request();
        request.setInputId("user_1233423333");
        request.setOperation(3);
        outputStream.writeObject(request);
        outputStream.flush();
        String s;
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

and for the Server:

```
public class ServerSocketTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        Request request = (Request) inputStream.readObject();
        System.out.println(request.getInputId());
        System.out.println(request.getOperation());
        writer.write("ok");
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I think that this codes should work, but I don't know Why I get this error. Any idea, guys?

**EDIT:**

OS = windows 8.1 64-bit

I've tested on my Ubuntu and everything was ok.

Comment: Try to reset the network gateway of your computer, http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/42910/how-to-reset-your-computers-gateway-ip-address/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test program is exiting without closing the socket. This causes the connection to be reset (TCP RST) instead of issuing an orderly close (TCP FIN). On some platforms.

Another problem is that you are reading lines in the client, but you aren't sending a line. You need to send a line terminator.

Comment: `You need to send a line terminator` Is this what I have suggested in the client and server side section.

Comment: still I am getting exception after closing the socket as well and writing new line character?  Have you tested the code?

Comment: @user3218114 You've now edited your answer extensively to agree with mine. Feel free but don't expect my assistance with it. I haven't posted any code to test, so I don't know what your second comment is about.

Answer (score 0):

#### Client side

Try any one

1. `readLine()` method looks for a complete line or a string that is ended by new line character `\n`.
2. Use `Scanner` that contains `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` methods.

#### Server Side

Try any one

1. Append new line character `\n` in the message for e.g. `ok\n`.
2. Use `PrintWriter` instead of `BufferedWriter` and use `println()` method that automatically appends a new line character in the message. Use **`auto-flush`** property of the `PrintWriter` to avoid calling `flush()` method manually.

Complete sample code:

ServerSocketTest.java

```
public class ServerSocketTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()),
                    true);
            System.out.println(inputStream.readObject());
            writer.println("ok");
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

SocketTest.java

```
public class SocketTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 5000);
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            outputStream.writeObject("Hello");
            String s;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Completely incorrect from start to finish. If there isn't a complete line to be read, readLine() will ***block*** until there is, or end of stream occurs. In the latter case it will return the partial line if any, otherwise null. See the stack trace. readLine() didn't throw this exception at all: the underlying read() method did that, in response to an event that had happened to the connection. It has nothing to do with lines whatsoever. -1

Comment: @EJP Thanks for input, please can you explain me why the above mentioned code works well after changing it to `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter#println()` or adding `\n` in the message?

Comment: I note that you've completely changed this answer to agree with mine since I posted the comment above. If you have a question of your own you should post it as a question.

Comment: @EJP thanks again for sharing your knowledge. I think I need to learn more about it.

Comment: If your state of knowledge is deficient you should be asking questions, not answering them.

Comment: whatever try to learn by running the programs. I tried the above code and it works that's why I shared it.